# Does Amazon's RDS Multi-AZ deployment cost twice as much as the normal cost of a single instance?

Tags: database, amazon-aws, pricing

It's not totally clear based on Amazon's provided documentation. Intuitively, it feels like it'd cost twice as much as a normal RDS instance for a two-zone deployment; does anyone here have experience with this, and could confirm or disconfirm that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Amazon's RDS pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/) has two sections.   One for Single-AZ Deployment and one for Multi-AZ Deployment.

Yes, Multi-AZ is about twice the price of Single-AZ.  For example I see:

- db.t2.micro single - $0.017/hour
- db.t2.micro multi - $0.034/hour

Answer (score 4):

To estimate the RDS cost I recommend the [AWS Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#s=RDS).

For a `db.m4.large` PostgreSQL instance I get the following:

- Single-AZ - $140.13/month - no High Availability
- Multi-AZ - $280.25/month

This means: **Single-AZ cost = ½ Multi-AZ cost**

Below two screenshots:

**Single-AZ**

[image: RDS Single-AZ AWS Simple Monthly Calculator estimation]

**Multi-AZ**

[image: RDS Multi-AZ AWS Simple Monthly Calculator estimation]

PS: no data transfer costs, no additional backup costs included

Answer (score 3):

Old thread but it's searchable...

If you run multiple instances in multiple AZs, of course you pay for each instance.  There is some additional data replication costs but the BIG miss here is that you have two instances to handle your load.  If this follows the pattern of many more DB  reads than writes that is common in apps, I would have the consumers deployed to 2 or 3 AZs with writes going to the "main" instance distributing reads across both instances.

Having two instances and and only using one is not the best imlementation

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: *Yes it does Kent*.

It costs twice as much.
Because it's two instances.